# range of timestamp series in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, dataframe

I have a dataframe df with columns in timestamp. I wonder is there a one line command that can return the range of timestamp, i.e, return the earliest timestamp and latest timestamp. How to sort the df rows based on timestamp?

```
df['StartDate'][:5]
Out[8]: 
0    2015/02/17 00:16:27
1    2015/02/17 00:16:27
2    2015/02/17 00:16:27
3    2015/02/17 00:16:27
4    2015/02/17 00:16:27
Name: StartDate, dtype: object
```

update:  John Galt and Joris provided the answer df['StartDate'].min() and df['StartDate'].max() solution. Joris further provided the answer df.sort('StartDate')

Comment: `df['StartDate'].min()` and `df['StartDate'].max()` may be?

Comment: You can just sort, that should work. And getting `.min()` and `.max()` should work as well to get the range

Comment: Thanks for @joris and John Galt. so I should use something like df.sort(index = StartDate, ascending = true) to sort df by startdate column? I will look into the command manual

Comment: ``df.sort('StartDate')`` will do (ascending is the default)